# Verilog Assignment nth iteration

Tags: verilog

I have the following code:

```
always @ (clk) begin 
  for (1=0,i<150, i++) begin
    abc[i] = xyz[i];
  end
end
```

Question: If I want to get value of `abc[8]` (set of 8th iteration with the assign statement), how can I do that?

I did like below:

```
reg [31:0] abc;
wire [31:0] jkl;

always @ (clk) begin 
  for (1=0,i<150, i++) begin
    abc[i] = xyz[i];
  end
end 

assign jkl = abc[8];

$display ("value is 0x%x\n", jkl);
```

I have an error, can you please suggest me something?

Comment: You have at least two syntax errors or typos: `for (1=0` should that be `i=0`?  Also please provide the error message.

Comment: sorry its my typo: its i=0 not 1=0.   Error is " expecting the keyword 'endmodule'". However, I do have endmodule in my code. If I remove assign statement then error goes. so, I just need how should I assign 8th set of iteration to a temp variable so that I can check wether the temp value is overwritten or not.

Comment: You should edit your question to fix the typo.

Comment: Apart from the points that @dwikle raises, you may have meant `always @(posedge clk)` currently the blocks will trigger on both edges of the clock.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you have misunderstanding of how for loops work in Verilog. In Verilog, you are defining hardware which operates in parallel at all times. The for loop is just a handy way to express something.  You should not think of it as iterating.

What your expression means is something like this:

> > Assign `abc[i]` from `xyz[i]` for all values of `i` from 0 to 149, **on every clock cycle**

If you really want to iterate, you need to create a counter which increments on each cycles and use that instead of a for loop.

---

Now, you are probably getting error messages due to some of your other errors:

1. You cannot put a `$display` outside of a sequential code block. That is, it needs to be inside an `always` or `forever` block or similar.
2. You are assigning `jkl` (a 32-bit value) from `abc[8]` which is a single bit
3. You are assigning `abc[0]` to `abc[149]` in the for loop, but `abc` is only 32-bits wide